# Can the [java-netowrk-programming] tag be removed (burninated)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [java-netowrk-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-netowrk-programming) tag is an obvious mis-spelling. It should go away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it looks like someone may have taken care of your request already. There are no more questions tagged with that tag.

The tag will be removed in the next 24 hours automatically since it isn't used on any posts.

Comment: I noticed this while reviewing new tags and removed it.